# how to change color of links in dropdown menu in navbar toggle

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navigation bar has a dropdown menu that looks like this.
[image]
when I resize my browser to get the small device version it looks like this.
[image]

I want to change the color of links in the dropdown(services) to black but I don't know which class to select for CSS.
I tried this but didn't work out.

```
.dropdown-menu {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #00ff99;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
     float: none;
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
}
.navbar-toggle .dropdown-menu > li > a{
     color: black;
}
```

this is my HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   @Html.ActionLink("E-HealthCare", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand shadow" })
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "About", "Home")</li>
   @*
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.DropDownList("Services","ALL")</li>
   *@
   <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="Dropdown-btn btn-block text-left dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
         Services
         <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if this works.

```css
ul.dropdown-menu > li > a {color:black !important;}
```

Comment: thank you it worked.  is there any other way of doing it without using !important?

Comment: you can try removing it and see if it still works on your code. you can also put a class on your link thats other way, like  a.blacklink {color:black}  then put a class on your links that you want.

Comment: it works only when I use !important in both cases. btw thanks for answering

Comment: another way is put it inline like <a style="color:black"></a>. I'm glad it worked for you. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go futher more with this. Because the one you need to go to is `.dropdown-menu > li > a > li > ul` which is in my opinion is too heavy. Try add this one to your code

```
#dropdown {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked.

Comment: So sorry ab that. I'm new too